# iphone & ipad app using default sounds

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4, audio, ipad

I have an app with a few sounds already in... but I Was wondering if there was a way to allow the user to select from a list of the default sounds which are on the device? If so, how does one go about making the list of these sounds (and are you indeed allowed to use them?!)

Thanks.